# How to disable a toolbar LabelTool in wxpython

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

I have created a `LabelTool` item in a toolbar. I want to know how to disable this item.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you disable a label? Labels are only for viewing purposes. The user cannot interact with them anyway.

EDIT: It looks like Robin Dunn answered a similar question (maybe yours?) on the wxPython mailing list today: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/wxpython-users/eO9GXO8R6eM

He gave the following example:

```
toolbar.EnableTool(toolId, True)  # or False to disable
```

Which is the code you would use to Enable / Disable any tool bar widget